If $D$ is a divisor on a curve and $P$ is not a base point of $D$, then $\ell(D-P)=\ell(D)-1$
In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter IV, remark 4.10.9, $X$ is a curve and $K$ is a canonical divisor. He states that $l(K) = g$ and $l(K-P_1) = g-1$ if we take $P_1$ not a base point of $K$.
I know $l(K) = g$. But I do not know how to prove this fact about the dimension of $H^0(X, \mathscr{O}(K-P_1))$.

Heuristic argument: If you have a vector space of functions on $X$, it imposes one linear condition to say that a function vanishes at $P$, unless they all happen to.

As already explained earlier in chapter IV:

Proposition IV.3.1. Let $D$ be a divisor on a curve. Then:
(a) the complete linear system $|D|$ has no base points if and only if for every point $P\in C$, $$\dim |D-P| = \dim |D| - 1;$$

The proof is direct: tensor the standard exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{O}_C(-P) \to \mathcal{O}_C \to k(P)\to 0$ by $\mathcal{O}_C(D)$. As $\mathcal{O}_C(D)$ is invertible, we get an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{O}_C(D-P) \to \mathcal{O}_C(D) \to k(P) \to 0$, and taking global sections we get $$0\to \Gamma(C,\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)) \to \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_C(D)) \to k.$$ But $P$ is a base point of $D$ iff for every global section $s\in \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_C(D))$, we have $s_P\in\mathfrak{m}_P\mathcal{O}_{C,P}(D)$, which is exactly the kernel of $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_C(D)) \to k$. In that case, the map $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_C(D)) \to k$ is zero, and $\Gamma(C,\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)) \to \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_C(D))$ is an isomorphism. So $l(D-P)=l(D)-1$ iff $P$ is not a base point of $D$.
